# Sequelize MySQL - Join with two rows from same associated table

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am into a tricky question involving Sequelize MySQL. I have two models: `Calibration` and `Device`, associated many-to-one respectively.

```
const Calibration = sequelize.define('Calibration', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            primaryKey: true,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4
        },
        date: {
            type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
            allowNull: false
        },
        document: DataTypes.STRING,
        status: DataTypes.STRING
    });

    Calibration.associate = (models) => {
        models.Calibration.belongsTo(models.Device, {
            foreignKey: 'deviceId',
            onDelete: 'CASCADE'
        });
    };


const Device = sequelize.define('Device', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            primaryKey: true,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4
        },
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        description: DataTypes.STRING,
        serialNo: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true
        },
        calibrationPeriod: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        location: DataTypes.STRING,
        seller: DataTypes.STRING,
        servicePartner: DataTypes.STRING,
        deviceFunction: DataTypes.STRING,
        quantity: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        status: DataTypes.STRING,
        comment: DataTypes.STRING
    });
```

Now the point is that I want to query a list of `Device`, joined with `Calibration`, each device item has two date attributes referencing two associated calibrations, one with most recent date and the other with the nearest date in future. It has been quite tricky and I haven't managed to find out solution. Thank you very much for your help.

Updated: This is my current doing, in fact, I'm not satisfied with this yet, as I prefer another way of combining it all in 1 query only, instead of 3 like this:

```
let result = await Device.findAll({
                    include: [{ model: Category, attributes: ['id', 'name'] }],
                    order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']], raw: true
                });
await Promise.map(result, async (item, i) => {
    const lastCalibration = await Calibration.findAll({
                        attributes: ['id', 'date'],
                        where: { date: { [Op.lte]: Sequelize.fn('curdate') }, deviceId: item.id },
                        include: [{ model: Device, attributes: ['id'] }],
                        order: [['date', 'DESC']],
                        limit: 1,
                        raw: true
                    });
    const nextCalibration = await Calibration.findAll({
                        attributes: ['id', 'date'],
                        where: { date: { [Op.gt]: Sequelize.fn('curdate') }, deviceId: item.id },
                        include: [{ model: Device, attributes: ['id'] }],
                        order: [['date', 'ASC']],
                        limit: 1,
                        raw: true
                    });
result[i] = { ...item, lastCalibration: lastCalibration[0], nextCalibration: nextCalibration[0] };
```

Comment: Can you share SQL that you want to generate using Sequelize?

Comment: In hibernate, this kind of association can be achieved with a join table to gain flexibility and scalability. So you’d look out how to achieve join table in Sequelize.

Comment: @SohamLawar Well, the point is that I myself now could not think of such a query like that

Comment: @tksilicon May you help me with an example? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the associations can be achieved through:

```
include: [Calibration], 
through: { 
    where: {
      [Op.or]: [
      { date1: '10-12-2020' },
      { date2: '11-12-2020' }
    ]
   }
 },
```

Comment: Look a the query, my friend, I doubt if you understand my needed query correctly :(

Comment: What I understand is that your device has two associated calibration dates. So when you join the table, the two foreign keys defined on the date1  and date2 would be used and checked in op.or. Share you Sequelize query.

Comment: As I understand your query, it is something like to choose a calib@ration between these two days. But in fact, it is something else, I will update my question